# how to get Identity PasswordOptions in ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to read the Identity `PasswordOptions` that are configured in `Startup.cs` from an MVC `Controller`. My `PasswordOptions` is configured like this:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config => {
        config.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
});
```

How do I then read the `RequireDigit`, `PasswordLength`, and `RequireNonAlphanumeric` properties in a `Controller` or elsewhere in the app?

Using ASP.NET Core 1.0.1.

Comment: You cannot, if you want to know these values elsewhere in your app to show in validators or on screen information then I suggest you store the values in your config file and have your password options retrieve the values from there as well as anywhere else you may want to use the values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply inject `IOptions<IdentityOptions>` interface to any class or controller's constructor like this:

```
 public class MyController : Controller
 {
     private readonly IOptions<IdentityOptions> _identityOptions;
     public MyContoller(IOptions<IdentityOptions> identityOptions)
     {
         _identityOptions=identityOptions?.Value ?? new IdentityOptions();         
     }

     public MyAction()
     {
         var length=_identityOptions.Value.Password.RequiredLength;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ah, IdentityOptions was what I was looking for. Thanks!